# Rails changing who the model "belongs_to" by changing which model ID is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a slightly complicated model for my "attachments" that belongs to a "quote".  I have a model "order" that could make use of this model but the attachments are separate.  Can I have 2 "belong_to's" on the attachments and only set the id for 1?  Is there a penalty to doing this over just creating an attachment model specifically for the order attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a polymorphic association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Thanks, that what i was looking for.  Though out of curiosity, is it still a bad idea if I have a model that belongs_to :order and belongs_to :quote then only give it one id? If so, why?  Since this is already very used, I'd rather avoid changing the model names everywhere for the as: :new_name.

Comment: If you use it you will have two fields as foreign keys, the id field and the type field, so that will be a slower lookup. You can improve that with an index. It will take up more space in the DB since you now have an extra string field and optionally the index. I would say the only advantage is if you needed all attachments in one table because you will be working with those as a separate entity regardless of associated table, and you would have many of those tables so that using a SQL UNION would become cumbersome.

Comment: If you are storing the attachment ID in the quote and order tables that is totally fine since you are just reusing a single image. If you are storing order ID and quote ID in the attachments table that's where the polymorphic would come in.

Comment: @suavocado Sometimes models grows and expands in the future. Therefore only if you're absolutely sure that your model `belongs_to A OR belongs_to B`, then that's only when I suggest you to use polymorhpic associations. But if your model MIGHT grow and then might `belongs_to A AND belongs_to B` in the future, then do not use polymorphic associations. That being said, I really love polymorhpic associations in that in makes my code DRY, because it would seem like your model will work automatically even whatever model it belongs_to (you'll have to know how this works though)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Very helpful, it would be nice to have the code be lighter. I'm just trying to avoid having to refactor everything that the original model was originally intended for